# How to call two APIs' using redux and getDerivedStateFromProps and componentdidupdate

Tags: reactjs, api, react-redux

Trying to call two API's through react-redux. Have written reducer and actions.Please find the code.

``````````
`````````
     home.js
    componentDidMount() {
    const URL = GET_ALL_ENTITIES;
    const ETURL = GET_ALL_TENANT_ENTITIES;

     this.props.GetAllEntitesAction(URL,header,"DISPLAY_ALL");
      // how to catch below api response
     this.props.GetTenantEntitesAction(ETURL,header,"DISPLAY_ALL_TENANTS")

    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevProps) {
    if (nextProps.responseData != prevProps.responseData) {
      return {
        responseData: nextProps.responseData,
      };
    }
       return null;
   }

   componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (this.props.responseData != this.state.response) {
        this.setState({ 
        response: this.props.responseData,
        });
      }
   }

  render() {
    let {response}=this.state;
    console.log("allentitiesData",response.allentitiesData)
    console.log("alltenants",response.alltenants) //Getting undefined
   }


    reducer.js
     let newState = {};
      const HomeReducer = (state=[],action)=>{

       switch (action.type) {
         case 'DISPLAY_ALL':
          newState.allentitiesData = action.payload;
          break;

          case 'DISPLAY_ALL_TENANTS':
          newState.alltenants = action.payload;
          break;

       default: return state;
     }

     return newState;
 };

  export default HomeReducer;
``````````

If I call both the API's, one of them gets overridden or undefined. How to 
  I catch and display both he responses. I have tried with set state as
   response: this.props.responseData.allentitiesData, but it gives 'maximum 
   update depth exceeded componentdidupdate' error. How can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

The 'maximum update depth exceeded componentDidUpdate' error is caused by an infinite loop.

`this.props.responseData != this.state.response` will always return `true` if `props.responseData` or `state.response` is an Object. This is because you are trying to compare them by reference. Because of that, your code will keep calling `this.setState` and it will trigger another `componentDidUpdate`.

You can use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual) to check Object equality.